# Real world scale issues with QGraphicsView / QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I am having some scaling issues - I suspect I am missing something... perhaps someone could set me straight.

I am using a QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView to display a boat's position using latitude and longitude in decimal degrees. For the un-initiated the positions looks like this:

LON: -71.34253 LAT: 41.549886

These are the positions I am setting for my custom QGraphicsItem objects. These are "real world" coordinates.

My problems is I can't seem to get my objects to display properly and I suspect I am not understanding the scale I should be using when I draw in my paint() function.

I am using Qt via PyQt, but this should be the same, no? Here is my custom class which represents a position.

```
class myGraphicsFix(QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

            self.lat = 0.0
            self.lon = 0.0

            self.boatlength = 1.5696e-6 # assuming 6371 km earth diameter, 10 m boat length

    def setLatLon(self, tlat, tlon):
            self.lat = tlat
            self.lon = tlon
            self.setPos(self.lat, self.lon)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
            pen = QPen(Qt.SolidLine)
            pen.setColor(Qt.black)
            pen.setWidth(0.0)
            painter.drawPoint(QPointF(0.0,0.0))

    def boundingRect(self):
            return QRectF(-self.boatlength/2.0,-self.boatlength/2.0, +self.boatlength/2.0, self.boatlength)
```

When this code runs all I get is a solid block of black, implying that somehow my points are being drawn as giant squares. If I replace drawPoint with drawEllipse() as follows:

```
painter.drawEllipse(-self.boatlength/2.0,-self.boatlength/2.0, self.boatlength, self.boatlength)
```

Nothing gets drawn at all... Any thoughts?

Tom.

Comment: In the first case you create a pen of line width 0 and do not use it. How do you get something? In the second case you draw an ellipse of a very tiny radius with large coordinates centre. How do you try to find it?

Comment: Thanks ilotXXI. The pen in my first case was a leftover from having the drawEllipse code in there. You are right that the drawEllipse code is weird - I changed it to having 0,0, and half the boat length for X and Y radii but I still get the same thing. My question really is what should I be using for a radius? Real world coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Glad to answer my own question...

Yes, the scale to be used in the QGraphicsItem is the "real world" scale.

The problem I was having was that I wasn't calling the drawEllipse function properly. Here is the cleaned up code that works. Note the QPointF() object in the argument.

```
    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
            pen = QPen()
            pen.setWidth(0)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(0.0,0.0), +self.boatlength/2.0, self.boatlength/2.0)
```

Note that in the `__init__()` method I have `self.boatlength = 0.00001` which corresponds to the boat in "real world" units (Here decimal degrees on the surface of the earth).

Things now work like a charm.